# Using hibernate return wrong count value of a query

Tags: java, mysql, sql, hibernate

I'm trying to check if there is an username in a database that is equal to the passed String.
This is the method.

```
public  boolean alredyTakenUsername(String userna) {
   int numb = 0;
   s = sessionFactory.openSession();
   try {
       String sql = "SELECT COUNT(*) FROM User where User.username= :usern";
       Query query = s.createQuery(sql);
       query.setParameter("usern",userna);
       numb = ((Number)query.getSingleResult()).intValue();
       if (numb == 1)
           return true;
       else
           return false;
   }catch (Exception e){
       e.printStackTrace();
   } finally {
       s.close();
   }
   return false;
}
```

I put in the database the username and with the query:

`select count(*) from User where username='fabio'`

TABLE:

```
USER( username CHAR(20),
      pass CHAR(40),
      loggedstatus BOOLEAN,
      PRIMARY KEY(username));
```

It returns 1 that is correct.
But the method always return 0 when i use `userna=fabio`.
I can't use `uniqueResult()` because Hibernate5 doesn't allow it.
Why?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the problem like this:

```
public  boolean alredyTakenUsername(String userna) {
   s = sessionFactory.openSession();

   try {
       String sql = "SELECT COUNT(*) FROM User where User.username= :usern";
       NativeQuery sqlQuery = s.createSQLQuery(sql);
       sqlQuery.setParameter("usern",userna);
       int numb = ((Number)sqlQuery.getSingleResult()).intValue();
       if (numb == 1)
           return true;
       else
           return false;
   } catch (Exception e){
       e.printStackTrace();
   } finally {
       s.close();
   }
   return false;
}
```

I think that the mistake was due at the use of the class `Query` that is specific for a query of Hibernate.
`NativeQuery` admit query of the dialect, in my case SQL (like the method that i use)